# Doesn't suspend when closing lid on a Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: dell, suspend, settings

This is what advanced settings tell me:

- Shell > Laptop lid close action on battery > `Suspend`
- Shell > Laptop lid close action when on AC > `Suspend`

The screen is on when I open the lid after closing for a few seconds. But not when I suspend from the session menu.

Still the battery on my Dell inspiron N5110 is always empty when I get back to it after closing the lid.

'Why?' is my question.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't suspend? What does it do? Does it turn of the screen? What about the LEDs? The battery can empty quite fast also in suspend mode.

Comment: The battery shouldn't empty so fast after closing the lid, it didn't on windows.

Comment: What is "so fast"?  I guess lumbric's point is that how do you know it's not a battery problem, for example?  So here's a test you can do.  Get super close to the laptop and kind of underneath so that when you lift the lid a bit, you can see if the screen is off and flickers on.  Also, does it suspend properly when you select that option from the session menu?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. We need more information what is actually happening. I'm not an expert in this, [but there are ways to get debugging information for suspend problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) for the case, that your screen just turns black, but doesn't suspend and wake up correctly.

Comment: The screen is on when I open the lid after closing for a few seconds. But not when I suspend from the session menu.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: Yes, question seems abandoned, however, I think the lid sensor isn't being detected in Ubuntu for this notebook. Can AWE verify this by running `watch -n 1 'upower -d | grep lid-'` and closing/opening the lid a few times and posting the output?

Comment: This is not a problem any more. Don't remember what I did if anything :(   gertvdijk's command output  `lid-is-closed:   no lid-is-present:  yes`

Comment: VTC as not reproducible. As OP last comment problem went away on its own. I have a sister laptop from the same era as OP's -- Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE and there are specific problems and solutions with suspend and resume. This Question doesn't provide enough specifics, is with an EOL version and likely EOL kernel.