# HP 510 laptop doesn't suspend when I close the lid

Tags: suspend, lid

I have an HP 510 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.
I have all the correct settings for suspending when the lid is closed, as far as I can tell, so I think it's a problem with detecting the event.
The way it "should" be detected, from what I can see, is a little hardware switch that is pushed when the lid closes. This switch manually puts off the backlight, and sends the suspend signal. All I can think is that the signal isn't being properly interpreted.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

**Update:**
I tested whether the button was actually working based on the suggestion by *josinalvo*, and I found that in the directory `/proc/acpi/button/lid/` there is no `LID` directory. There is, however, a `C1CF` folder, and in it is a state file. 
When using the this file instead of `LID`, I discovered that, no, when I close the lid, the state does not change.
The full path is: '/proc/acpi/button/lid/C1CF/state

**Update 2**
I'm now running Xubuntu 12.10, (Unity was to slow) but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/122856/dont-want-to-suspend-when-closing-lid or here http://askubuntu.com/questions/122250/doesnt-suspend-when-closing-lid

Comment: The second possible duplicate link doesn't have answers.

Answer (score 4):

To know if the button is indeed working, go to a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/) and type

```
while [ 1 ]; do cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state; sleep 1; done
```

you should get one

```
state:      open
```

every second. Now close the lid and wait a bit. Open it again. Some lines should now be

```
state:      closed
```

with that, you can tell that the hardware is working, and the signal is read by linux

---

If it is working, well, I have no idea what your problem is =P

However, I have an ugly kludge you can use while your problem is not fixed

```
#ensures that a closed lid causes the computer to suspend
#! /bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
sleep 20
grep closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state && sudo pm-suspend
done
```

This is a bash script.

To use it,

1) create a file with these contents (say, check_lid)
2) right click the file, and open properties
2.1) go to permissions, and select 'allow executing file as a program'
3) on the shutdown menu, go to Startup Applications and add your program (check_lid) to the programs in startup
4) Ensure that your user can run sudo pm-suspend without using a password (via the sudoers file)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.
I've updated my question with results.

Comment: I am not sure you are looking at the right file ...

could you do a `find /proc` and post it somewhere ?
(a good place to put it might be http://textsave.de )

Comment: also, if you could point to the full path file you are reading, it would be nice

Comment: @yuri

please give us a bit more information (as described in my previous  comments)

Comment: Sorry for not checking in in a while. The full path is: /proc/acpi/button/lid/C1CF/state 
The output for 'find /proc' is here: 
http://textsave.de/?p=153599
Do you want me to add it to the question?

Comment: @yuri sorry, but I cant see the text ... is the link working properly ?

Comment: I think it exceeds some limit on textsave.de. It's 71937 lines! Same on pastebin.com, and on friendpaste.com loading the page with the paste almost crashed my browser! I could try a few more, but I'm not sure it would help.

Comment: you are right. I wanted to examine it to see if there was any other possible file that was reporting the lid state correctly, but /proc/acpi/button/lid/C1CF/state seems to be the right place to look =(

Comment: Ah well. Tell me if you have any more ideas. I've kind of learned to live with it, now. All the same, it would be nice to have everything working properly.

Comment: You might be interested in:

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=512958

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/1037860